# How can I find the minimum value of an algebraic expression as a function of some parameters?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
Minimize[
  {
    (2 a (a^2 - c^2))/(a^2 - c^2 Cos[θ]^2), 
    0 <= θ < π, a > 0, c > 0, a > c
  }, {a, c, θ}
] // FullSimplify
```

The expected result would be:

```
(2 a (a^2 - c^2))/(a^2 - c^2 Cos[θ]^2)
```

This formula contains three parameters, but $a$ and $c$ are considered constants, so the sought after results will still contain $a$ and $c$. I want to find the minimum value of this expression as a function of $a$ and $c$, but I have been unable to find it using the above code.

When `θ== π/2`, I get the correct answer:  `(2 (a^2 - c^2))/a`.

```
Minimize[{(2 a (a^2 - c^2))/(a^2 - c^2 cos^2), -1 <= cos <= 1, a > 0, 
  c > 0, a > c}, {cos}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that theta only appears in Cos. Therefore, you can do without Cos and define another variable, call it cos with -1<=cos<=1. With this you get:

```
Maximize[{(2 a (a^2 - c^2))/(a^2 - c^2 cos^2), -1 <= cos <= 1, a > 0, 
  c > 0, a > c}, {a, c, cos}]
```

This produces the warning:

```
Maximize::natt: The maximum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints.
```

Well, note further, that 1/(a^2 - c^2 cos^2) achieves the largest value under the given constrains for cos= +/- 1. With this we still get the same warning.

But, note further, the target function: (2 a (a^2 - c^2))/(a^2 - c^2 ) simplifies to: 2a. Now it is clear that there is NO maximum.

Comment: to find minimum value

Comment: Use Minimize, and change `{a, c, cos}` to just `{cos}`.

Comment: Minimize[{(2 a (a^2 - c^2))/(a^2 - c^2 cos^2), -1 <= cos <= 1, a > 0, 
  c > 0, a > c}, {cos}]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NMinimize[{(2 a (a^2 - c^2))/(a^2 - c^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2), 0 <= \[Theta] < \[Pi] , a > c > 0}, {a, c, \[Theta]}]
{1.24647*10^-10, {a -> 1.48842, c -> 1.48842, \[Theta] -> 2.3277}}
```

**addendum**

With new parameter `cda=c/a` we get functional

`(2 a (a^2 - c^2))/(a^2 - c^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)==a (2 (1 - cda^2))/(1 - cda^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)`

to be minimized for `0<cda<1`. Because `a>0` it is only necessary to look at `(2 (1 - cda^2))/(1 - cda^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)`

```
Plot3D[(2 (1 - cda^2))/(1 - cda^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2), {cda, 0, 1},{\[Theta], 0, Pi}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
```

[image]

Obviously there is no unique minimum! Minimal value is 0 at `c/a==1` and `0<\[Theta]<1`.

Comment: That's not the answer. The answer must contain parameters a and c. The correct answer is:```(2 (a^2 - c^2))/a```

Comment: @csn899 Minimization is done fo `a ,c,\[Theta]`, that's why the numerical result doesn't depend on these parameters!